# Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

am having a problem with my application in vb.net where by when i insert my date from a `datetimepicker` to a `mysql database` the value which i see is 0000-00-00 and when i try to retrieve that record i get the following error message -
Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.  If you use a parameterized query, it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

In MS-SQL I insert my dates using a `CONVERT(datetime, datetimepicker.value, 103)` The 103 sets the format to `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.sss`.

You may have to do something similar

Comment: Basically something like...
INSERT INTO TABLE (Col1, Date, Col2) Values ('XXX', CONVERT(datetime, datetimepicker.selecteddate, 103), 'YYY')
NOTE that this is what I use in MS-SQL it may not work in MySQL